# How to find the derivative w.r.t. lower limits?

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule

How to find $\frac{d}{dy} \int_{y}^{\infty} \int_{2y}^{\infty} y f(x_2)dx_2 f(x_1)dx_1$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two independent continuous random variables and $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ are their PDFs. Can I still use Leibniz's rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case: let $f$ be an integrable function with antiderivative $F$, then

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dy}\int_y^a f(x)dx = \frac{d}{dy}\left( F(a)-F(y)\right) = -f(y).
\end{align*}

And if we manipulate your expression a bit it becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_{y}^{\infty} \int_{2y}^{\infty} y f(x_2)dx_2 f(x_1)dx_1 = y\int_{y}^{\infty} f(x_1)dx_1\int_{2y}^{\infty} f(x_2)dx_2
\end{align*}
which you can now easily differentiate w.r.t. $y$ using the product rule and what I wrote above.

Comment: Thank you @StiftungWarentest! Does the general case you mentioned apply as well when a=infinity? So Leibniz's rule is not needed in this case even though one of the limits is a function of y?

Comment: As long as $\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}F(a)$ exists, $a=\infty$ is no problem. About Leibniz's rule: I guess you will need it for the lower bound of $2y$

Comment: Thank you! What is the result for $\frac{d}{dy} \int_{y}^{\infty}f(x_1)dx_1 \int_{2y}^{\infty} f(x_2)dx_2$? What do you do after taking the derivative for the first part, i.e., $\int_{y}^{\infty}f(x_1)dx_1$?

Comment: If $y>0$, you could consider substituting $(x_1,x_2)=\left(\frac1{X_1},\frac1{X_2}\right)$ before differentiating, if you feel that's easier to approach:$$\int_0^{1/y}\int_0^{2/y}\frac y{X_1^2X_2^2}f\left(\frac1{X_1}\right)f\left(\frac1{X_2}\right)\,dX_2\,dX_1$$